# Google custom image search - only returns website images

Tags: java, image, google-chrome

I want to fetch some google images with the Google custom search API. But instead of the google images Iam getting the thumbnails of the websites. Here an example:

Iam getting the link of these thumbnail images:
[image]

But I want to have the links of these images:
[image]

Maybe somoene can tell me how to do that!

The Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String key = "";
    String cx = "";
    String keyword = "coke";

    URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=" + key + "&cx=" + cx + "&q=" + keyword);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");


    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {

        if((output.contains("jpg") || output.contains("png")) && output.contains("src")){                
            System.out.println(output);       //Will print the google search links
        }   
    }
    conn.disconnect();                              
   }
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't specifying that you want image search from Google. You are just searching for possible images in normal results. You'll need to add `searchType=image`.

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462292/google-custom-search-api-returns-0-results-when-searchtype-is-image) and learn more about querying [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list).